# How to show the users of this specific department?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function that shows the department as treeview,it checks for the root node and then checks if this department has child.When i click in a department it should redirect me at another page that shows the users of this department that was clicked.I have tried to write this code and it shows me all the users but i want only those of this department

DepartmentController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use  App\Department;
use  App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class DepartmentController extends Controller
{  

  public function usersdep(){
    //THIS IS THE ADDED CODE   

     $users =  DB::table('users')
    ->join('departments', 'users.department', '=', 'departments.id')
    ->select('users.id','users.lastname','users.name as username','departments.name')->get();
    return view('admin.page-users')->with('users', $users);
    //ADDED CODE
  } 



  public function treeView(){       
    $departments =  Department::where('parent', '=', 0)->get();   
    $tree='<ul id="browser" class="filetree">';
    foreach ($departments as $department) {     
      $tree .='<li class="tree-view closed "<a href="/page-users/.{{department->id}}" class="tree-name">'.$department->name.'</a>'; //first department
      if(count($department->childs)) {
        $tree .=$this->childView($department);// if this department has children               
      }
    }
    $tree .='</ul>';
    //return $tree;
    return view('admin.page',compact('tree'));
  } 

  public function childView($department){                 
    $html ='<ul>';

    foreach ($department->childs as $arr){

      if(count($arr->childs))
      {
        $html .='<li class="tree-view closed"><a  href="/page-users/.{{department->id}}" class="tree-name">'.$arr->name.'</a>';                  
        $html.= $this->childView($arr);
      }
      else
      {
        $html .='<li class="tree-view" ><a href="/page-users/.{{department->id}}" class="tree-name">'.$arr->name.'</a></a>';                                 
        $html .="</li>";
      }                                                
    }            
    $html .="</ul>";
    return $html;
  }
```

page-user.blade.php

```
@extends ('layouts.master')

@section('title')
Users | Admin
@endsection

@section('content') 

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card">
      @if (session('status'))
      <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        {{ session('status') }}
      </div>
      @endif
      <div class="card-header"> 
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table">
            <thead class=" text-primary">
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Department</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach($users as $row)
            <tr>
            <script>console.log($row)</script>
            <td>{{ $row->username }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->name}}</td> 
            </tr>
            @endforeach          
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  @endsection

  @section('scripts')

  @endsection
```

web.php

```
<?php
use App\User;
use App\Department;

use App\Events\WebsocketDemoEvent;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    broadcast(new WebsocketDemoEvent('some data'));
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/page', function () {
    return view('admin.page');
});
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','admin']], function  () {
    Route::get('/role-register','Admin\DashboardController@registered');
    Route::delete('/role-delete/{id}', 'Admin\DashboardController@registerdelete');//delete user
    Route::post('/save-user', 'Admin\DashboardController@store');

    Route::get('/department', 'Admin\DepartmentController@index');
    Route::post('/save-department', 'Admin\DepartmentController@store');
    Route::get('/department-edit/{id}', 'Admin\DepartmentController@edit');//edit department
    Route::put('/department-update/{id}', 'Admin\DepartmentController@update');
    Route::delete('/department-delete/{id}', 'Admin\DepartmentController@delete');//delete department  

    Route::get('/page-users/{id}', 'Admin\DepartmentController@usersdep');//show users  


});
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/chats', 'ChatsController@index');//chats
Route::get('/messages', 'ChatsController@fetchMessages');//messages
Route::post('/messages', 'ChatsController@sendMessage');//messages

Route::get('/dashboard', 'Admin\DashboardController@dbcheck');//DATABASE
Route::get('/user-edit/{id}', 'HomeController@registeredit');
Route::get('/role-edit/{id}', 'Admin\DashboardController@registeredit');//edit user
Route::put('/role-register-update/{id}', 'Admin\DashboardController@registerupdate');

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');


Route::get('store_image', 'StoreImageController@index');
Route::post('store_image/insert_image', 'StoreImageController@insert_image');
Route::get('store_image/fetch_image/{id}', 'StoreImageController@fetch_image');
Route::get('/page',array('as'=>'jquery.treeview','uses'=>'Admin\DepartmentController@treeView'));
Route::get('/pageusers', 'Admin\DepartmentController@usersdep');
```

User.php

```
    public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
    }
```

Department.php

```
public function users()
{

    return $this->hasMany(User::class,'department','id');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to define hasMany users relation for department class?

Comment: i have one to many user department relation let me update my question to add this

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: Good, when you click on department you can take its users with $department->users

Comment: the users show but they show in this url :        page-users/.%7B%7Bdepartment->id%7D%7D                                                                                                                   im not sure if this is right

Comment: shoudnt it be page-users/1 or is this okay?

Comment: i want to show the users of this specific department but im not sure how to edit the answer that you gave with the files that i have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you method like this, you need to find department by id passed to route and then get department users. You can also do it using eager loading.

EDITED: You don't have to take id from request, but as route param, so this have to work

```
public function usersdep($id){
    $department = Department::with('users')->find($id);
    return view('admin.page-users')->with('users', $department->users);
}
```

Comment: i tried this but gives me this error: Trying to get property 'users' of non-object

Comment: That means that Department not found in db, do you pass the right id to route?

Comment: this is what i wrote at the web file                                                                                                      Route::get('/page-users/{id}', 'Admin\DepartmentController@usersdep');//show users

Comment: this is the link that redirects me at this page  its in the treeview function that ive wrote above    ,                                                                                                                                        href="/page-users/.{{department->id}}"

Comment: The route definition is ok, but check if you get department by passed id param.
$department = Department::find($request->id);
dd($department);
Do you have null here?

Comment: if i write this line exactly it says null

Comment: you have a dot in your link, so id param in controller will be not 1 but .1, that's why department is not found.
href="/page-users/[. REMOVE this dot ]{{department->id}}"

Comment: i removed it but still the same it says null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208264/discussion-between-ruben-danielyan-and-k-learn).